# Whats wrong with following piece of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am creating iframe in which user can set height (stored in setHeight variable) by entering input but I am struck at following and failed to find solution.

```
document.write("<iframe src=\"" + decodeURIComponent(finalSearch) + "\" width=\"100\%\" height="setHeight">");
```

Please Help!

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not concatenating the variable setHeight into your string, and you're not escaping all of your double quotes. Try this:

```
document.write("<iframe src=\"" + decodeURIComponent(finalSearch) + "\" width=\"100\%\" height=\" + setHeight + \">");
```

Comment: unnecessarily escaped %

Comment: iframe is working but it is not setting height to that entered value.. How can I fix this https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288633/americanumlaut

Comment: @JohnD. Please ask another question that addresses your new issue, including an example of an iframe with the attribute set how you think it should work and a description of what it does instead.